# Is Jil vulnerable to Friday The 13th JSON attack?

Tags: .net, json

Is the .NET JSON (de-)serializer [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) vulnerable to Friday The 13th JSON attack when deserializing untrusted input? If this attack is applicable, how can it be prevented?

Explanation of the attack: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf